# Changing title of dojo dialog dynamically when refreshes the dialog

Tags: dojo, dialog

Does anyone know how to refresh the title bar of dojo dialog dynamically based on user's action?

For example, I click a link to open a dialog.  This dialog will have different links.  I then click on one of these links.  This dialog refreshes, and the title bar should be update with different text?

Dialog One: Title bar text:  Select Equipment | Step 1 of 3.   User clicks on a link, dialog one refreshes with new content and new title bar text: Select Equipment | Step 2 of 3 (with some styling).  User then clicks on a link on this dialog and it refreshes with new content.  The title bar now should show: Select Equipment | Step 3 of 3.

Any answers, hints, helps are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the title attribute.

```
 dlg.set('title', newTitle);
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/DnBTW/